# How can I improve my program in Python for reversing words in a string

Tags: python

I have solved this problem, but still feel I could improve in some areas.

I know this problem can be solved using **slicing** and **reversed** build- in functions.But I am doing this as a practice for interview coding questions.So wanted this way

How did I approach in solving the problem:

1. Covert the input string to a list . I did this since in python
   strings are immutable.
2. Reverse the entire list of characters
3. Reverse the individual words.
4. #Problem area:Once the list is ready with the words reversed , joining back to a string dealing with spaces seems to be problematic to me.
   ex: INPUT:' helpful   is overflow  stack  ' -- > Output 'stack overflow is helpful'

   ### ## My Code ##

`class Solution:
    # @param word, a list of chars
    # @param startInd, an int
    # @param endInd, an int
    # @return a list of reversed characters
    def reverseChars(self,word,starIndex,endIndex):
        lengthWord = endIndex-starIndex+1
        # Reverse the characters of the word by swapping the corresponding chars
        # Looping for only lengthWord/2 times should suffice
        for i in xrange(0,lengthWord/2):
            word[starIndex + i],word[endIndex-i]=word[endIndex-i],word[starIndex +i]
        return word`

```
# @param s, a string
# @return a string
def reverseWords(self, s):
    #Convert given input string into list of characters.
    listChars = list(s)

    #First reverse the entire string.
    self.reverseChars(listChars,0,len(listChars)-1)

    # Iterate through the list of reversed chars and reverse individual word.
    # Iterate through the list till we find a space and then call the reverseChars function.
    startind = 0 
    endind = -1
    space = ' '
    for x in listChars:
        if(x == space):
            if(listChars[startind]== startind<len(listChars)-1):
                startind+=1
                endind+=1
            else:
                self.reverseChars(listChars,startind,endind)
                endind = endind+1
                startind = endind + 1
        else:
            endind+=1
    self.reverseChars(listChars,startind,endind)
--> return ' '.join(''.join(listChars).split())
```

**Can my last return statement with join statements be improved?**

Comment: What's wrong with `' '.join(reversed(str.split()))` ?

Comment: What are you reversing ? The characters in the words or the words in the sentence?